# Javascript Instances and this

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, eventemitter

I am writing a little tool in node.js, here is the part that is bothering me:

```
function Active(name, options, data){
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
  var that = this;
  that.name = name;
  that.options = options;
  that.data = data;
  that.getData();
  that.on('ActiveStart', that.createLogFile);
  that.on('ActiveDone', that.removeLogFile);
  function callback() {
    that.emit('ActiveDone');
  }
  var getData = function() {
  // starts other processes outside of the scope of this function
  // callback() gets passed around and called from outside function
  }
  getData();
 }


util.inherits(Active,events.EventEmitter);

Active.prototype.createLogFile = function () {
  this.filename = this.name + '-' + this.options + '.log';
  fs.outputFile('./log/' + this.filename,data,function (err) { // fs-extra
    if(err) return console.log(err);
  });
};

Active.prototype.removeLogFile = function () {
  fs.remove('./log/' + this.filename,function (err) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
  });
};


Active.prototype.findData = function () {
    var that = this;

    routes.findOneAndUpdate({},update,{sort: _sort},function (err,doc) { // update and _sort are in 'global' scope
      if(err) return console.log(err);
      that.emit('ActiveStart',doc.info,doc.data); // the variables are for a different event handler
    });

};
```

Active has some other methods which do the lifting, I am having trouble with the log file though. I start the process with

```
new Active('hello','123','data');
```

and the logfile is created. As long as I have just one instance of Active, everything is fine. If I start

```
new Active('second','456','moredata');
```

before the first log is deleted, the removeLogFile later removes the second logfile because `this` does not point to the first instance, but the second. Why is that? Dont I create two different scopes with the `new` operator?

Comment: do you assign each new Active to separate vars?

Comment: no I don't, I just start them (thinking they would keep their scope) and dont access them directly in any way after I run the `new Active()` except for the events

Comment: Can you show us how you call `emit` on them? The value of `this` depends on which instance you invoke it on; that's the only possible source of a mistake I can see there.

Comment: Just pointing out: there is a syntax error in your second code example, missing a quote '.

Comment: I edited the code to include as much information as possible

Comment: Usually the source of this problem is that in some place you forgot the `var` before `that`, making it global and firing callbacks on the wrong (last created) instance. However, I cannot find such in your code.

Comment: I think there missed important part of code.
Can you update your example to minimal working state (delete ```that.getData()```, call ```callback``` somewere) to presetn this bug? 
(Recomendation) -> Also ```that``` is bad practice in your situation (in all situations) - you need to pass the context where it is possible (use ```function.bind``` instead of ```that``` - it simplify your code and in future you can switch fast to arrow notation functions, what saves the context).

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` depends on the caller. One way you can avoid this problem is by using scope instead of prototypal inheritance to get references to your variables.

```
function Active(name, options, data){
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    var that = this;
    that.name = name;
    that.options = options;
    that.data = data;
    that.on('ActiveStart', createLogFile);
    that.on('ActiveDone', removeLogFile);

    function createLogFile() {
        that.filename = that.name + '-' + that.options + '.log';
        fs.outputFile('./log/' + that.filename,data,function (err) { // fs-extra
            if(err) return console.log(err);
        });
    };

    function removeLogFile() {
        fs.remove('./log/' + that.filename,function (err) {
            if(err) return console.log(err);
        });
    };
}

util.inherits(Active,events.EventEmitter);
```

Comment: Hm, but in `EventEmitter` callbacks the `this` is always the event emitter… So the original code should work as well.

Comment: True, but I couldn't find anything wrong with it. So I figured I'd give a way of avoiding the issue. That way we can verify the problem is where we think it is.